# is cookie function similar to header function in php?

Tags: php, http-headers

I need to know when I use setcookie() function in php is it actually similar to using headers()?

If i use:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", 'value');
```

is equal to

```
header("Set-Cookie: TestCookie:value;");
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically yes. However `setcookie` also validates the correct usage and format and possibly sets some workarounds for MSIE for you. Whereas the `header` function will just send a raw header and you have to make sure that what you put in there is actually correct usage for setting the cookie.

You can check the implementation for `setcookie` at:

- http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/head.c#php_setcookie

The implementation for `header` is in:

- http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/head.c#php_header